# One liner command to extract #of ID occurrences in a very long file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have the following really huge file (million lines) with the following format:

Timestamp, ID, GUID

Example:

```
2014-04-14 23:59:59,754 2294 123B24C6452231DC1770FE37E6F3D51168
2014-04-14 23:59:59,757 102254 B9E0CE6C9F67745326F9FD07C5B31B4E1D65
```

ID is a number which can be any from single digit and up to 6 digits.
GUID has a constant length (as above).

I would like to get #of occurrences for each ID in the file.

Output should looks something like:

```
Count, ID
8 2294
15 102254
```

...

I am trying to get this with a single grep using uniq and sort without much succeess.

Appreciate help.

Comment: I don't see the single grep uniq and sort that you have been using.

Answer (score 3):

If there are single spaces in between the fields (as in your example) rather than commas (as in your format), then you could use:

```
cut -d' ' -f3 hugefile | sort | uniq -c
```

Another alternative, if the separator might be several spaces:

```
awk '{print $3}' hugefile | sort | uniq -c
```

You could also do all the work inside the `awk` program (untested):

```
awk '{c[$3]++} END { for (n in c) print c[n], n }' hugefile
```

Comment: `awk '{a[$3]++}END{for (i in a) print a[i], i }' hugefile` isn't a simple one-liner?

Comment: @steffen `uniq` requires sorted input as it only checks adjacent lines.

Comment: @veryhungrymike: it wasn't simple enough to just type into the answer on the first try. But I was working on it just as you were.

Comment: it's in my muscle memory. I guess I use that idiom too often.

Comment: Thanks guys - awk '{print $3}' hugefile | sort | uniq -c  really did the trick, fast and as expected. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
grep -Po '(?<= )[0-9]+ ' yourfile | sort | uniq -c
```